# Angular JS select all/De select all checkboxes how to retrieve selected information

Tags: javascript, angularjs, json, checkbox

I am displaying output response(JSON) from REST  API using Angular JS. I am planning to provide user with an option of checkbox for every result listed and also a selectall/deselectall checkbox .I am stuck at implementing select all/deselect all implementation , how to implement selectall/deselect all checkbox and also  how to retrieve the selected checkbox information and form a JSON object of all the Id selected .I would love to do it the angular way

This is my Controller call

```
   $http.post('http://localhost:8080/services/search/'+id+"", searchCriteria).then(function(response) {
     $scope.searchresponse = response.data.items;
     if($scope.searchresponse.length != 0){
       console.log($scope.searchresponse);
     }
     else {
       $scope.showerror = true;
       $scope.ErrorMsg ="There is no record matching your criteria."
     }
   });
```

This is my JSON Response from REST

```
{
    "items": [{
        "customerId": "ABC",
        "type": "D"
    }, {
        "customerId": "DEF",
        "type": "A"
    }],
    "more": false
}
```

This is my HTML

```
    <tr ng-repeat="details in successresponse">
        <td align="left" class="validationMsg">
            <input type="checkbox" name="entireday" id="entireday">
            {{details.customerId}}
            {{details.type}}
        </td>
    </tr>
```

I would like to implement select all / deselect option and retrieve the customer ids selected and form a JSON object

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add a selected field on each of the search response items:

```
$http.post('http://localhost:8080/services/search/'+id+"", searchCriteria).then(function(response) {

    if (response.data && response.data.items.length != 0) {
        $scope.searchresponse = response.data.items.map(function (x) {
            x.selected = false;
            return x;
        });
        console.log($scope.searchresponse);
    } 
    else {
        $scope.showerror = true;
        $scope.ErrorMsg ="There is no record matching your criteria."
    }
});
```

Template:

```
<tr ng-repeat="details in successresponse">
    <td align="left" class="validationMsg">
        <input type="checkbox" name="entireday" id="entireday" 
               ng-model="details.selected">
        {{details.customerId}}
        {{details.type}}
    </td>
</tr>
```

then to select all/ de-select all, you can write:

```
$scope.selectAll = function() {
    angular.forEach($scope.searchresponse, function (x) {
        x.selected = true;
    });
}

$scope.deselectAll = function() {
    angular.forEach($scope.searchresponse, function (x) {
        x.selected = false;
    });
};
```

And to get the values that were selected:

```
function getSelected() {
    return $scope.searchresponse.filter(function (x) {
        return x.selected;
    });
}

// alternative implementation
var getSelected = [].filter.bind(
    $scope.searchresponse, 
    function (x) { return x.selected; });
```

Comment: Why do we need to set the checkbox inside the controller . how should  i call the getselected function to retrieve values inside the controller  and form a JSON object containing only customerid

Comment: You need to initialize the checkbox in the controller because that is where you get the initial set of values from your REST endpoint.  You can call getSelected to get the items from the list that are selected at whatever point you need them.  For example when calling another REST endpoint, you can just do, `data = getSelected().map(function (x) { return x.customer_id; });` to get just the customer IDs.  Also, you had very minimal code in your OP.  If you want more detail, you have to provide a lot more detail.

Comment: I am getting this error when i try to retrieve the value -   Array.prototype.filter called on null or undefined

Comment: That means you didn’t initialize `$scope.searchresponse` in your controller.

Comment: @hey 2ps , How can i return customer type along with the id . I would like to construct JSON obj for my rest call . so that i can take the details of customer id and type and loop through it and do some validations

Comment: when i return x , it has all details as an object , now how can i construct my JSON in a way it has list of items , but in my REST i should be able to take details like this is the customer id and this is the type so do some validations

Comment: Praveen, can you update your question with an example of what you are looking for?